# Autofac Web API Dependency Injection Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autofac

[Visual Studio - Snapshot of Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JGRS.png)

Global.asax.cs file where I have put the dependencies and register the webAPI controller

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;
using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;
using StructureMap;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using GeoLocationApi.Services;
using GeoLocationApi.Controllers;
using GeoLocationApi.Models;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GeoLocationApi
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);



            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


            builder.RegisterType<locationService>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(locationController).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterType<locationContext>().As<locationContext>().InstancePerRequest();
            builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);


            var container = builder.Build();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        }
    }
}
```

locationService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using GeoLocationApi.Models;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace GeoLocationApi.Services
{
    public partial class locationService : IlocationService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<location> _locationRepository;

        public locationService(IRepository<location> locationRepository)
        {
            this._locationRepository = locationRepository;
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<location> GetAllLocations(params Expression<Func<location, object>>[] includeProperties)
        {
            return _locationRepository.Table.IncludeProperties(includeProperties);
        }
    }
}
```

locationController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using GeoLocationApi.Models;
using GeoLocationApi.Services;
using GeoLocationApi.Infrastructure;

namespace GeoLocationApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class locationController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IlocationService _locationService;

        public locationController(IlocationService locationService)
        {
            this._locationService = locationService;
        }

        [Route("getlocation")]
        [HttpGet]
        public locationDTO GetLocationDetails()
        {
           var data = _locationService.GetAllLocations().Where(x => x.locationActiveStatus != false);

            return AutoMapperConfiguration.Mapper.Map<locationDTO>(data);

        }
    }
}
```

IRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GeoLocationApi.Models;

namespace GeoLocationApi.Services
{
    public partial interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get entity by identifier
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Identifier</param>
        /// <returns>Entity</returns>
        T GetById(object id);

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
        void Insert(T entity);

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities">Entities</param>
        void Insert(IEnumerable<T> entities);

        /// <summary>
        /// Update entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
        void Update(T entity);

        /// <summary>
        /// Update entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities">Entities</param>
        void Update(IEnumerable<T> entities);

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete entity
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
        void Delete(T entity);

        /// <summary>
        /// Delete entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entities">Entities</param>
        void Delete(IEnumerable<T> entities);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a table
        /// </summary>
        IQueryable<T> Table { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a table with "no tracking" enabled (EF feature) Use it only when you load record(s) only for read-only operations
        /// </summary>
        IQueryable<T> TableNoTracking { get; }


    }
}
```

locationContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace GeoLocationApi.Models
{
    public class locationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<location> Location { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

location.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace GeoLocationApi.Models
{
    public class location : BaseEntity
    {
        public string locationName { get; set; }
        public string locationDescription { get; set; }
        public string locationLongitude { get; set; }
        public string locationLatitutde { get; set; }
        public bool locationActiveStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I run the project, I am getting the error in the browser tab which is regarding contructor.

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'locationController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = locationController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [GeoLocationApi.Controllers.locationController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'GeoLocationApi.Controllers.locationController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'GeoLocationApi.Services.IlocationService locationService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(GeoLocationApi.Services.IlocationService)'. (See inner exception for details.)
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType) at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
</StackTrace>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'GeoLocationApi.Controllers.locationController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 'GeoLocationApi.Services.IlocationService locationService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(GeoLocationApi.Services.IlocationService)'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
</StackTrace>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Error>
```

As i am new to both Stackoverflow and ASP.NET WEB API, i need you to please explain me the issue and tell me the error why it is coming.

Thanks in advance and help is appreciated.

Comment: When posting a question on Stackoverflow, always try to come up with a good title. The main question should be in the title. Always thing about the 'gooblebility' of your question and a good question interests others to read through your question. "Autofac Web API Dependency Injection Issue" is _not_ a good title. See [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're registering your `locationService` wrongly, it should be mapped to the **interface**, not the **actual** class

`builder.RegisterType<locationService>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest()`

Comment: Thanks for helping but still i am getting the error.

https://s1.postimg.org/1rcxjfajzj/Still-error.png (Snapshot)

Comment: I guess it's *new error*, have you registered your `repository`?

Comment: can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: do you have `LocationRepository` class?

Comment: No I don't have, actually I was following the tutorial as there was LocationRepositry file in the structure.

Comment: Can you elaborate where should I add this file and the content I have to add in it in order to run the project ?

Comment: unfortunately each project has a different structure, you might want to re-look at the tutorial, or you can copy and paste the tutorial link here. I'll try to take a look at the tutorial

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have created a Repository Class and registered the same with Global.asax.cs file and now it's working. But now I am getting some Null Reference Error. Can you please check and help me out?

I have been trying this out from past few hours but not getting it. Attached the error screenshot.

https://s1.postimg.org/1dm6uih6yn/Null-reference.png